# UISwitch, something similar for Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, uiswitch

I’m sure most of you are familiar with the `UISwitch` on iOS.

Is their any existing project trying to implement something like a `UISwitch` for macOS and AppKit?

If not, where would one start to make one? I see them frequently and can think of so many uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used the Mondo Switch that's part of the [Cocoa Mondo Kit](https://github.com/mcormier/CocoaMondoKit).  It works pretty well.

Comment: Since this seems to be an IB plugin it's most likely outdated.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @Sentry.co fixed

Answer (score 15):

I think you should use `NSCheckBox` since it is the equivalent on a computer where you use a mouse and not your finger.

Comment: `UISwitch` can have different semantics, though: it can embody an _action_ rather than data (like turning Time Machine on, whose preference pane uses a similar control).

Comment: Bavarious - Where and how does apple get that switch in XCode? I think it's stupid it should be available for mac too..

Comment: The Time Machine switch existed before iPhone, FYI.

Comment: I can't find NSCheckBox class anywhere

Comment: A checkbox is an option of the `NSButton` class.

Comment: I agree we need to use Checkbox

Answer (score 7):

For anyone that comes across this question in the future, I have developed a UISwitch for Mac (MacToggle) **Swift 3 & AutoLayout**

https://github.com/RichAppz/MacToggle

[image]

It's a replica of the iOS UISwitch and fully customisable.

Enjoy

Comment: How can adjust height width of view accordingly

Answer (score 6):

I [recently extended](https://bitbucket.org/dainkaplan/cocoa-on-off-switch-control) Peter Hosey's [PRHOnOffButton](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/prhonoffbutton/wiki/Home) to add iOS-like background colors and labels. Since mine is derived, it may or may not have the same caveat described above by Peter.

[image]

Comment: It's been quite a while since I needed a switch. After the upgrade to Xcode 4 and having Mondo Switch no longer work, I wrote an view based switch as part of my personal framework.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Peter Hosey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30461/peter-hosey)’s [PRHOnOffButton](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/prhonoffbutton/overview/).

Comment: Caveat: There are some bugs in the public source that I have fixed locally, but haven't pushed the fixes for yet. Those who want a real UISwitch-like control should follow PRHOnOffButton on Bitbucket (or subscribe to its feed) in order to be notified when I make those fixes final and public.

Answer (score 3):

`ITSwitch` requires no images, integrates with Interface Builder and has lovely (modern) animations:

> https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITSwitch

Recommended.

Answer (score 3):

starting with macOS 10.15 'Catalina' there is a native control for that called `NSSwitch`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsswitch?language=objc

Comment: Unfortunately we need our apps to work on older versions of macOS like El Capitan or Mojave. So the NSSwitch wont work on those OS's