# How to change the tint colour of NSSwitch?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

The NSSwitch looks right now pretty pale:

[image]

I'm trying to change the tint colour like this on iOS:

[image]

But there is no tint colour section on IB like it is on iOS.

So I'm trying my luck in the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var alwaysConnectedSwitch: NSSwitch!

override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    self.alwaysConnectedSwitch.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.init(gray: 1, alpha: 1)
}
```

But the `self.alwaysConnectedSwitch.layer` seems to be nil, so nothing is set.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811942/uiswitch-something-similar-for-mac/58070331#58070331) post. Maybe you can use one of the libraries or see how its done.

Comment: It's intriguing, but risky, as it hasn't been updated for three years.

Comment: Are you trying to change the disabled color or the enabled color?

Comment: Disabled colour.  But happy to know both. Thanks

Comment: @Houman Looks like this gets super tricky as the color is determined by NSWidgetView (private) and it goes through an updateLayer pass. If I figure out how exactly it creates the specific color, I'll let you know, but there is no public API. NSSwitch doesn't use NSCell for it's drawing either, so there aren't many hooks. Whatever the solution would be, it would end up utilizing private API.

Comment: @Houman Well I found a reliable swizzling approach that works if you're interested. There may be a way of subclassing NSSlider to vend a particular view color but it will be private API.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Thanks I have no experience with the private API. Will Apple accept it? A shame that NS classes are not as extensive as their counter UI classes.

Comment: @Houman It would not be accepted into the Mac App Store. You could distribute it outside of the App Store though. My advice if you are targeting the App Store would be to use a different custom control that looks similar and gives you what you want, or just to use what Apple gives you. I'll try to post my private solution anyways if you want to see it.

Comment: Since the introduction of SwiftUI it's pretty easy to display a `Toggle` in any desired color in an `NSHostingView`.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely need to change the style, I'd recommend a 3rd-party custom control that lets you customize the look as you desire; some viable suggestions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811942/uiswitch-something-similar-for-mac). As of 10.15, `NSSwitch` simply doesn't have the customization you desire. If you don't care about details, stop reading now

That said, it's interesting to dissect the components of `NSSwitch`. Unlike many Cocoa controls, there is no backing `NSCell` for this control. The documentation says this explicitly:

> NSSwitch doesn’t use an instance of NSCell to provide its functionality. The cellClass class property and cell instance property both return nil, and they ignore attempts to set a non-nil value.

So instead, it is a rather modern control made up of layers that draw the content. There are 3 `NSWidgetView`s which are private `NSView` subclasses.

[image]

These views mostly utilize `-[NSView updateLayer]` to draw into their backing CALayer desired values based on what they're fed via `-[NSWidgetView setWidgetDefinition:]`. This method passes in a dictionary of values that defines how `NSWidgetView` should draw into the layer. An example dictionary for the back-most view:

```
{
    kCUIPresentationStateKey = kCUIPresentationStateInactive;
    kCUIScaleKey = 2;
    kCUIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionKey = kCUIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionLeftToRight;
    size = regular;
    state = normal;
    value = 0;
    widget = kCUIWidgetSwitchFill;
}
```

Unfortunately, this means that the style is mostly determined by predefined strings as seen by `widget = kCUIWidgetSwitchFill;` It gets quite involved in how this fill color or disabled color is drawn depending on system color (dark/light) or highlight color. The colors are tied to NSAppearance and there isn't a clear way of overriding any of these.

One (not recommended, seriously don't do this) solution is to swizzle out the `updateLayer` call for NSWidgetView and do your own additional layer customization in the cases that you desire. An example written in Swift:

```
/// Swizzle out NSWidgetView's updateLayer for our own implementation
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    /// Swizzle out NSWidgetView's updateLayer for our own implementation
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let original = Selector("updateLayer")
        let swizzle = Selector("xxx_updateLayer")
        if let widgetClass = NSClassFromString("NSWidgetView"),
            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(widgetClass, original),
            let swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSView.self, swizzle) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzleMethod)
        }
    }
}

extension NSView {
    @objc func xxx_updateLayer() {
        // This calls the original implementation so all other NSWidgetViews will have the right look
        self.xxx_updateLayer()

        guard let dictionary = self.value(forKey: "widgetDefinition") as? [String: Any],
            let widget = dictionary["widget"] as? String,
            let value = (dictionary["value"] as? NSNumber)?.intValue else {
            return
        }

        // If we're specifically dealing with this case, change the colors and remove the contents which are set in the enabled switch case
        if widget == "kCUIWidgetSwitchFill" {
            layer?.contents = nil;
            if value == 0 {
                layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor;
            } else {
                layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellow.cgColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, DON'T DO THIS! You're bound to break in the future, Apple will reject this in an App Store submission, and you're much more safe with a custom control that does exactly what you want without mucking with private API.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks Lucas. I will look into custom controls then. Is there at least a chance to set the border? `self.alwaysConnectedSwitch.layer?.borderColor = .black` Even that doesn't work.

Comment: I actually went with the first suggestion in the link you pasted. I picked a checkbox, which makes sense too. But it also comes with issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672767/how-to-remove-the-white-box-around-the-nsbutton-checkbox-when-disabled

Answer (score 1):

Since the introduction of `SwiftUI` and `NSHostingView` you can take advantage of the flawless integration of `SwiftUI Views` in `AppKit/UIKit`.

- First create a simple `SwiftUI` view with a `Toggle` and an `@ObservedObject` property which represents the view controller. You can specify any tint color.

  ```
  struct SwitchView: View {
      @ObservedObject var model : ViewController

      var body: some View {
          Toggle("Switch", isOn: $model.isOn)
              .toggleStyle(.switch)
              .tint(.orange)
      }
  }
  ```
- In the `NSViewController` adopt `ObservableObject`, import `SwiftUI`, add a `@Published` property `isOn`, an `IBOutlet` for the `NSView` and initialize the `NSHostingView` lazily

  ```
  import SwiftUI

  class ViewController : NSViewController, ObservableObject {

      @IBOutlet weak var switchView: NSView!

      @Published var isOn = false

      lazy var toggleView = NSHostingView(rootView: SwitchView(model: self))
  ```
- In Interface Builder drag an `NSView` in the canvas, resize it and connect it to `switchView`
- To attach the hosting view to the `IBOutlet` add a generic method `attachHostingView` und call it in `awakeFromNib`

  ```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        attachHostingView(toggleView, to: switchView)
  }

  fileprivate func attachHostingView<V : View>(_ hostingView: NSHostingView<V>, to superView: NSView) {
      hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      superView.addSubview(hostingView)
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
          hostingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.leadingAnchor),
          hostingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.trailingAnchor),
          hostingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.topAnchor),
          hostingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.bottomAnchor),
      ])
  }
  ```
- There are three options to perform an action when the switch changes the state: The `didSet` property observer of `isOn`, the `Combine` framework or the `onChange` modifier in the `SwiftUI` view calling a custom method in the view controller.

That's it. Enjoy a switch with the tint color of your choice.

Comment: Be aware that in SwiftUI on the mac, the preview is incorrect: it shows a gray switch. But running the actual app shows the correct tint color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding exactly wich kind of problems you're facing, but this is working for me:

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    zzz.layer!.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemRed.cgColor
    zzz.layer!.masksToBounds = true
    zzz.layer!.cornerRadius = 10
```

This yelds

[image]

You may wish to play/adjust other border settings like borderWidth or borderColor