# How to remove the white box around the NSButton checkbox when disabled?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

**Update:**

I have added a demo on my Github to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/houmie/CocoaPlayground

**Build and start the app, then click on the menu symbol as shown below.**
[image]

---

There is not much code to this. Adding a NSButton with Style `Check` and Type `Switch` into IB.
In IB it looks fine. But starting the app there is a white box appearing around the disabled checkbox. The background is obviously grey hence it shows.

Is there a way to remove/override that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your image (the png) have a white background? Or does the UIButton have a background color of white?

Comment: Not sure what you did there, but if you're adding it via IB, search for "check box" and drag one of those out. There shouldn't be any border around the button itself...

Comment: Guys, I have added a demo on my GitHub, I would really appreciate your help: https://github.com/houmie/CocoaPlayground